# "stack level too deep" When Processing Carrierwave Image Versions in Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

This is a strange problem and, unfortunately, it has many potential sources. I am using carrierwave and cocoon gems to help with nested file uploads. Any type of version processing I do in my uploader causes a stack level too deep error. If I remove the processing, it saves the nested images normally. I have tried to do a lot of troubleshooting and have narrowed it down to that; for example, if I remove just the version processing, then it works normally. If I remove everything except the version processing, it throws the same error. There is a lot of potential source, so here is some code:

**parent form (truncated)**

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@object, @discussion], multipart: true , input_html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
     <div id="pictures">
      <%= f.semantic_fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
        <%= render 'picture_fields', :f => p %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association f, :pictures do %>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add Image</button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

**nested form**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <%= f.input :pic, label: false %>
    <%= f.input :pic_cache, as: :hidden %>    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
    <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">REMOVE</button>
    <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**uploader**

```
        # encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    if Rails.env.test?
      "uploads/test/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    else
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  #custom method to access local files as full paths
  def local_path_or_remote_url
    if CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.storage.to_s == CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.storage_engines[:file]
      path
    else
      url
    end
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [72, 72]
  end


  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    "pic#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}" if original_filename
  end

end
```

I have uploaders that use essentially the same code without problems. It's only with the nesting that this versioning code has problems. I know there can be a lot of potential sources for this. Any ideas?

Comment: when you use `<%= render 'picture_fields', :f => p %>` the partial `'picture_fields'` is the nested form you provided?

Comment: yup. _picture_fields.html.erb

Comment: You seem to pinpoint the problem to the "version processing", and where is that?

Comment: Its in the uploader:
 process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [72, 72]
  end

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

Answer (score 2):

I switched from rmagick to mini_magick and it works now...