# Stack level too deep when using carrierwave versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm trying to use a [sidekiq worker](https://gist.github.com/mbajur/eea25199f67ac89ac348#file-extract_keyframes_worker-rb-L38), which more or less saves a image file to database (using carrierwave). There are few files to save, which are a keyframes extracted from a video file. That's what that worker is about.

My image uploader has a few versions defined and looks as follows:

```
class KeyframeUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # ...

  # Keyframe thumbnail sizes
  version :small do
    process resize_to_fill: [180, 180], if: :square?
    process resize_to_fill: [320, 180], if: :not_square?
  end

  version :medium do
    process resize_to_fill: [460, 460], if: :square?
    process resize_to_fill: [640, 460], if: :not_square?
  end

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [720, 720], if: :square?
    process resize_to_fill: [1280, 720], if: :not_square?
  end


  private

    # Checks if image is a square
    def square? file
      img = Magick::Image.read(file.path)
      img[0].columns == img[0].rows
    end

    # Oposite to #square?
    def not_square? file
      !square? file
    end

end
```

The thing is, when i'm trying to run my Sidekiq Worker, it throws `Celluloid::FiberStackError: stack level too deep` and the only way to fix that is to remove my version definitions. It works only if there are not any version assigned to the uploader.

I have tried moving a save process to another worker or using Carrierwave::Backgrounder but i'm allways getting the same result.

Have you any idea what can i do about it?

---

Edit: My stracktrace is:

> SystemStackError: stack level too deep    from
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/workspace.rb:86

Comment: FYI `Stack Level Too Deep` means you've got an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: yep, i know that. The problem is i can't figure out where i can have it. I feel a bit that it's not my fault but the carrierwave's.

Comment: Could you show us your worker too?

Comment: it's linked by "sidekiq worker" words in first sentence ;)

Comment: What do you see if you add a `puts '...'` in `square?`?

Comment: You have a tiny bug in your code. For 31 secs you'll have 6 frames, for 60 you'll have 3 frames. 60 is covered in "else"... Not important, just note it.

Comment: Have you searched the backtrace (stack trace) to find the repeated part in it? There must be some recursion going on.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace here? Also, which version of carrierwave/sidekiq are you using?

Comment: Well, it's quite unuseful but i've added it to original question (that's what i'm getting when saving an image from IRB)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It turned out, that it's a carrierwave's fault (well, actually, osx fault). Thread with explanation: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1330

#### Solution:

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

Comment: Whooooop. Saved my day!

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Even though the error you got has `Celluloid::` in it, this issue seems to not be part of the `celluloid` tag. Do you agree?

Comment: yeah, totally. Celluloid tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

i would target the for loop in your worker.

```
for i in 1..(frames_to_extract)
```

you're not incrementing *i* but you seem to be doing an indexed loop. I would switch it to use **enum** and **each_with_index**.

Rubyists tend to avoid the **for** loop as its a nasty mess.

Comment: This seems likely to be the problem... You would probably see a whole bunch of identical "Taking screenshot from..." log entries, if it is in fact the issue.

Comment: Well, it's also acts like that when i'm uploading an image outside of sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your models, see if you have got an after_save hook for example which would regress into an infinite loop if you update the record in that hook - it's possible you've got an after_save which creates the job to make thumbnails and then storing those thumbnails initiates another job
2. check for thread-safety issues, are any of the gems you are using listed [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Gems-known-not-to-be-threadsafe)
3. check your stack trace, can you see which lines are repeating?
4. is the error present when you're not using sidekiq to process the files?
5. does the problem happen always or just under load?
6. RMagick bug with Ruby 2.1 - https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/100
7. ...

Comment: yes, that error is also there if i'm not using sidekiq for processing. Stacktrace added to original question.

Comment: How are you triggering the postprocessing? Through a callback? Also, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774686/stack-level-too-deep-when-processing-carrierwave-image-versions-in-nested-form?rq=1 ? Could be a postprocessing lib bug, what are you using to resize images? Can you post Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Yeah, i've seen that thread but i was always using rmagick without any problems and i would love to keep it that way. Gemfile.lock: https://gist.github.com/f859f467755ba6b82335 . About triggering the postprocessing - i'm not sure how to answer that, i'm triggering them in a regular way taken from carrierwave readme.

Comment: mbajur, as far as I can tell there's a bug in the version of RMagick you are using https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/100, see if your code works with a different postprocessing lib, if it does, try playing with RMagick version and/or ruby version until your code works, or failing that wait for good people at rmagick to fix the issue I linked

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I have posted a solution with explanation as an answer. Thanks for your support!