# Stack Level Too Deep error - produced with strong parameters I think

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I think the issue could be strong parameters in Rails 4, but I am not sure.

Here is what I have.

All I am trying to do is create a `post`, but when it gets submitted I get this error:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 06:06:57 -0500
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"daURJjzq2EMfiQZ/uiD/0ADg=", "post"=>{"status"=>"confirmed", "title"=>"Ashlee lost 10 pounds in 5 weeks", "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010652d3c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0f/hgplttnd7dg6q9m62qtbnpn00000gn/T/RackMultipart20140828-87750-gyz4np>, @original_filename="Ashlee-Testimonial.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[photo]\"; filename=\"Ashlee-Testimonial.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "body"=>"Ashlee lost 10 pounds in 5 weeks."}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 77ms

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79:in `'
```

A `Post` model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  status     :string(255)
#  title      :string(255)
#  date       :datetime
#  image      :string(255)
#  body       :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  user_id    :integer
#  ancestry   :string(255)
#  file       :string(255)
#

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :user
  resourcify

  mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

My `PostsController` looks like this:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:status, :title, :date, :photo, :body, :parent_id)
    end
```

This is what my form partial looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %> 
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :parent_id, as: :hidden %>

    <% if can? :manage, @post %>
      <%= f.input :status, collection: Status.all %>
    <% end %>       

    <%= f.input :title %><br />
    <%= f.input :date %><br />      
    <%= f.input :photo %><br />
    <%= f.input :body %><br />      

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this error?

**Update 1:**

When I create a post without a file being uploaded, it creates fine, as can be seen by the log below:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 06:34:50 -0500
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"daUAvh6w4dCH3sswJ6dckYRJjzq2EMfiQZ/uiD/0ADg=", "post"=>{"status"=>"confirmed", "title"=>"Test Post", "body"=>"Does this work at all."}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("body", "created_at", "status", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "Does this work at all."], ["created_at", "2014-08-28 11:34:50.886549"], ["status", "confirmed"], ["title", "Test Post"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-28 11:34:50.886549"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/2
Completed 302 Found in 83ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

So it seems the culprit is actually in Carrierwave/Fog/Strong Parameters somewhere in there.

Update 2:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem "font-awesome-rails"
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
end

group :development do
    gem 'annotate', github: 'ctran/annotate_models'
    gem 'sextant'
  gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.2"
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 1.1.0'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'
    gem 'meta_request'
    gem 'execjs'
    gem 'therubyracer'  
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'bullet'   
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'     
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require=>false
  gem 'guard-livereload', '~> 2.3.0', :require=>false
  gem 'rack-livereload', '~> 0.3.15'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.4'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.8.2'
gem 'rolify'
gem "rmagick"
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem "fog", "~> 1.3.1"
gem 'figaro', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.2.2'
gem 'social-share-button', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'ancestry', '~> 2.1.0'
gem "simple_form"
```

**Update 3:**

So it seems that this particular Stack Level Too Deep Error has been fixed, but the problem has just moved. I have created a new SO question here - [Exconn::Errors::SocketError in file upload via Carrierwave and Fog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550841/exconnerrorssocketerror-in-file-upload-via-carrierwave-and-fog)

Comment: it's happening when the post successfully saves or fails or both?

Comment: The post doesn't successfully save. It seems to roll it back. Edit 1: It seems that if I don't attach a file, then the post is successfully created. It is just when I do try to attach a file, that it does this it seems. Going to update the questions.

Comment: can you post your gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450955/2128691):

in your gemfile, change `gem "rmagick"` to

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1330

Comment: So it seems that got rid of that error, but now I have another error. I am going to create a new SO question and update it here with that new error. Can you take a look when I link it up?

Comment: Here is the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550841/exconnerrorssocketerror-in-file-upload-via-carrierwave-and-fog

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your database. You are setting strong parameter and mounting uploader for `photo` but your database have column with name `image`. Try change column name to `photo` would solve your issue. Also rmagick require if you are doing any resizing stuff.

Comment: It was the rmagick issue, it seems. That `photo` and `image` stuff is correct on my side. I did a lot of renaming and migrations. So anything you see in the question, was just an oversight in my copying. But the column in the db and the code reference match. I fixed it with dax's suggestion, but now I am getting another error. I am going to create a new SO question for that, and paste it here.

Comment: Here is the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550841/exconnerrorssocketerror-in-file-upload-via-carrierwave-and-fog